# Comparing filenames and determine their incremental digits

Tags: regex, perl

Imagine i have a sequence of files, e.g.:

```
...
segment8_400_av.ts
segment9_400_av.ts
segment10_400_av.ts
segment11_400_av.ts
segment12_400_av.ts
...
```

When the filenames are known, i can match against the filenames with a regular expression like:

```
/segment(\d+)_400_av\.ts/
```

Because i *know* the incremental pattern.

But what would be a generic approach to this? I mean how can i take two file names out of the list, compare them and find out where in the file name the counting part is, taking into account any other digits that can occur in the filename (the `400` in this case)?

**Goal:** What i want to do is to run the script against various file sequences to check for example for missing files, so this should be the first step to find out the numbering scheme. File sequences can occur in many different fashions, e.g.:

```
test_1.jpg (simple counting suffix)
test_2.jpg
...
```

or

```
segment9_400_av.ts  (counting part inbetween, with other static digits)
segment10_400_av.ts
...
```

or

```
01_trees_00008.dpx  (padded with zeros)
01_trees_00009.dpx
01_trees_00010.dpx
```

**Edit 2:** Probably my problem can be described more simple: With a given set of files, i want to:

1. Find out, *if* they are a numbered sequence of files, with the rules below
2. Get the first file number, get the last file number and file count
3. Detect missing files (gaps in the sequence)

Rules:

- As melpomene summarized in his answer, the file names only differ in one substring, which consists only of digits
- The counting digits can occur anywhere in the filename
- The digits can be padded with 0's (see example above)

I can do #2 and #3, what i am struggling with is #1 as a starting point.

Comment: Is it always just a single part of the string that changes?

Comment: Regex can't count, so if you do not know which is the increment you will have no chance with regex to find out. you could only maybe use one line as pattern and then use groups and back-references.

Comment: What output do you want from this?

Comment: @Fallen: This isn't about counting; it's about finding which substring is different between two strings that otherwise match.

Comment: You didn't say what your final goal is, why do you need that changing number? Maybe a better way to approach that goal is using [natural sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_sort_order).

Comment: Edited: I want to find out how the sequence 'works', to do further checks/counts. I hope, that makes sense.

Comment: *"I want to find out how the sequence 'works', to do further checks/counts"* Okay, but exactly what information do you need for these "checks and counts". Be precise. It may help to explain your overall problem at a higher level.

Comment: Thank you for the update, but it doesn't "work" for me completely.  I did update my answer, following the "_Goal_" update in the question.

Answer (score 1):

See if this works for you:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub compare {
    my ( $f1, $f2 ) = @_;

    my @f1 = split /(\d+)/sxm, $f1;
    my @f2 = split /(\d+)/sxm, $f2;

    my $i    = 0;
    my $out1 = q{};
    my $out2 = q{};
    foreach my $p (@f1) {
        if ( $p eq $f2[$i] ) {
            $out1 .= $p;
            $out2 .= $p;
        }
        else {
            $out1 .= sprintf ' ((%s)) ', $p;
            $out2 .= sprintf ' ((%s)) ', $f2[$i];
        }
        $i++;
    }

    print $out1 . "\n";
    print $out2 . "\n";
    return;
}

print "Test1:\n";
compare( 'segment8_400_av.ts', 'segment9_400_av.ts' );

print "\n\nTest2:\n";
compare( 'segment999_8_400_av.ts', 'segment999_9_400_av.ts' );
```

You basically split strings by starting/ending digits, the loop through the items and compare each of the 'pieces'. If they are equal, you accumulate. If not, then you highlight the differences and accumulate.

**Output** (I'm using ((number)) for the highlight)

```
Test1:
segment ((8)) _400_av.ts
segment ((9)) _400_av.ts


Test2:
segment999_ ((8)) _400_av.ts
segment999_ ((9)) _400_av.ts
```

Comment: Your `split` calls can be achieved with `split /(\d+/`.

Comment: Edited. Thanks, much better!

Answer (score 1):

I assume that only the counter differs across the strings

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

my ($fn1, $fn2) = ('segment8_400_av.ts', 'segment12_400_av.ts');

# Collect all numbers from all strings    
my @nums = map { [ /([0-9]+)/g ] } ($fn1, $fn2);

my ($n, $pos);  # which number in the string, at what position

# Find which differ
NUMS: 
for my $j (1..$#nums) {                           # strings
    for my $i (0..$#{$nums[0]}) {                 # numbers in a string
        if ($nums[$j]->[$i] != $nums[0]->[$i]) {  # it is i-th number
            $n = $i;
            $fn1 =~ /($nums[0]->[$i])/g;          # to find position
            $pos = $-[$i];
            say "It is $i-th number in a string. Position: $pos";
            last NUMS;
        }
    }
}
```

We loop over the array with arrayrefs of numbers found in each string, and over elements of each arrayref (eg `[8, 400]`). Each number  in a string (0th or 1st or ...) is compared to its counterpart in the 0-th string (array element); all other numbers are the same.

The number of interest is the one that differs and we record which number in a string it is (`$n`-th).

Then its position in the string is found by matching it again and using [`@-` regex variable](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#Variables-related-to-regular-expressions) with (the just established) index `$n`, so the offset of the start of the n-th match.  This part may be unneeded; while question edits helped I am still unsure whether the position may or not be useful.

Prints, with position counting from 0

```
It is 0-th number in a string. Position: 7
```

Note that, once it is found that it is the `$i`-th number, we can't use `index` to find its position; an number earlier in strings may happen to be the same as the `$i`-th one, in this string.

To test, modify input strings by adding the same number to each, before the one of interest.

---

Per question update, to examine the sequence (for missing files for instance), with the above findings you can collect counters for all strings in an array with hashrefs (num => filename)

```
use Data::Dump qw(dd);

my @seq =  map { { $num[$_]->[$n] => $fnames[$_] } } 0..$#fnames;

dd \@seq;
```

where `@fnames` contains filenames (like two picked for the example above, `$fn1` and `$fn2`). This assumes that the file list was sorted to begin with, or add the sort if it wasn't

```
my @seq =  
    sort { (keys %$a)[0] <=> (keys %$b)[0] }
    map { { $num[$_]->[$n] => $fnames[$_] } } 
    0..$#fnames;
```

The order is maintained by array.

Adding this to the above example (with two strings) adds to the print

```
[
  { 8 => "segment8_400_av.ts" },
  { 12 => "segment12_400_av.ts" },
]
```

With this all goals in "*Edit 2*" should be straighforward.

Comment: Still figuring out the counter 'detection' part, but will give the method of storing the numbers to hashrefs definitely a try. Would have done it way more complicated.

Comment: @dequid Thank you for feedback.  I simplified that part a little (changing the bit that finds the position) and added an explanation.  Let me know if isn't good enough.

Answer (score 1):

You tagged this question `regex`, so here's a regex-based solution:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $name1 = 'segment12_400_av.ts';
my $name2 = 'segment10_400_av.ts';

if (
    "$name1\0$name2" =~ m{
        \A
        ( \D*+ (?: \d++ \D++ )* )  # prefix
        ( \d++ )                   # numeric segment 1
        ( [^\0]* )                 # suffix
        \0                         # separator
        \1                         # prefix
        ( \d++ )                   # numeric segment 2
        \3                         # suffix
        \z
    }xa
) {
    print <<_EOT_;
Result of comparing "$name1" and "$name2"
Common prefix: $1
Common suffix: $3
Varying numeric parts: $2 / $4
Position of varying numeric part: $-[2]
_EOT_
}
```

Output:

```
Result of comparing "segment12_400_av.ts" and "segment10_400_av.ts"
Common prefix: segment
Common suffix: _400_av.ts
Varying numeric parts: 12 / 10
Position of varying numeric part: 7
```

It assumes that

- the strings are different (guard the condition with `$name1 ne $name2 && ...` if that's not guaranteed)
- there's only one substring that's different between the input strings (otherwise it won't find any match)
- the differing substring consists of digits only
- all digits surrounding the first point of difference are part of the varying increment (e.g. the example above recognizes `segment` as the common prefix, not `segment1`)

The idea is to combine the two names into a single string (separated by NUL, which is unambiguous because filenames can't contain `\0`), then let the regex engine do the hard work of finding the longest common prefix (using greediness and backtracking).

Because we're in a regex, we can get a bit more fancy than just finding the longest common prefix: We can make sure that the prefix doesn't end with a digit (see the `segment1` vs. `segment` case above) and we can verify that the suffix is also the same.

Comment: sorry, please see my both updates. The numeric segments can occur anywhere in the file name, even at the beginning and also there _can_ be another numeric part.

Comment: but don't you search for two numeric segments ( \d++ ). What if there is only one, the counting one? But i see, i have to study perlre...

Comment: @dequid `( \d++ )` is a group of 1 or more digits (possessive), meaning it will always match the maximum amount of currently available digits.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you build a regex pattern by changing all digit sequences to `(\d+)` and then see which captured values have changed

For instance, with `segment8_400_av.ts` and
`segment9_400_av.ts` you would generate a pattern `/segment(\d+)_(\d+)_av\.ts/`. Note that `s/\d+/(\d+)/g` will return the number of numeric fields, which you will need for the subsequent check

The first would capture `8` and `400` which the second would capture `9` and `400`. `8` is different from 9, so it is in that region of the string where the number varies

I can't really write much code as you don't say what sort of result you want from this process

Comment: Sorry for not making myself clear. I want this to work on generic file sequences without even knowing their filename.

Comment: So you want to find the differences between two filenames without seeing the filenames? That's clearly impossible.

Comment: I can see the filename, by taking for example the first two files. What i mean is, there is no predefined pattern, see my edited question. But yes, your approach seems to be my way to go.

Comment: @dequid: No, I realise that, which is why I suggested that you find all numeric fields in the names and see which one is different. It would help a lot if you answered the repeated questions about what result you want from this: I don't understand why you're avoiding it.